# ERROR: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/docker-springboot"): error=2, No such file or directory

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, cloudbees, docker-desktop

I'm running Jenkins on docker desktop for windows, with installed and configured docker plugin.
CloudBees Docker Build and Publish plugin in Jenkins and configured my docker hub details in build section
While build I am getting below error :

```
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/var/jenkins_home/workspace/docker-springboot"): error=2, No such file or directory

Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please, am I facing this issue due to running Jenkins on docker desktop or issue is something else?

Comment: Add jenkins user to the docker group and try again.

Comment: Souravatta i am using jenkins image and Running using docker desktop for Windows. So how to add jenkins user to any such group